# Changing the height of the items in a ListView

Tags: java, android-layout, listview, android

I'm designing an application to browse miscellaneous source code.
To browse the lines i chose to put them into a `ListView`.
I've already built my custom `Adapter` to handle custom item layout. All the heights are set to wrap_content, but android doesn't seem to care about that, there's an annoying blank space between the lines.

[Image](http://oi41.tinypic.com/2vaxrpi.jpg)

If I manually set the height value in layoutParams programmatically to a fixed value, i.e. 30, the problem is "fixed", but I find this solution ugly and want to understand the reason of this unwanted spacing.

Here's my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sourcerow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linenumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.06"
        android:minWidth="30dip"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="@string/line" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.94"
        android:padding="0dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/indent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thecode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="@string/code"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally this is my Adapter getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
    codeLine entry = code.getCode().get(pos);
    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_row, null);
    }
    if(pos%2==0) v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_1);
    else v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_2);
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.sourcerow);
    TextView linenumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.linenumber);
    TextView linecode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.thecode);
    TextView indent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.indent);
    linenumber.setText(Integer.toString(pos+1));
    indent.setText(indent(entry.getDepth()));
    linecode.setText(Html.fromHtml(entry.getCode()));
    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you removing the line breaks from the lines of code?

Comment: No, I tought they were removed automatically by fromHtml(). This worked

Comment: `fromHTML()` will actually convert those into <br> .